# Unknown Type of data to return in linq to xml query

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I want to return an anonymous data retreived from a query in Linq. I dont know which kind of List<> return because the data is "var" anonymous.

```
          public List<?????> QueryXmlUserLogin()
         { 
          var data = from item in XDocumentObj.Descendants("User_Data")
                   select new   
                   {
                       user = item.Element("user").Value,
                       password = item.Element("password").Value,
                   };

         data.ToList();

         return ????
```

Comment: Just a side idea, looking at the variable names, you don't store passwords, do you?

Comment: I do but the File which contais XDocument is encrypted

Comment: well then it is not really the best idea securitywise, it doesn't really matter if you encrypt a file or even encrypt each password or both. It is a considerably large vector for an attack, where a hacker obtains your encryption key and decrypt the file/passwords. A more secure approach is to store a generated strong hash of a password. Thus you don't store passwords at all, only an inreversable "garbage". Everytime user logs in, you reapply hash to the provided password and compare it to the stored hash. But this of coz depends if you care about security of that application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two data types come to mind, a `Tuple<string, string>` or a `KeyValuePair<string, string>` depending on their intended usage:

```
public List<Tuple<string, string>> QueryXmlUserLogin()
{ 
    var data = from item in XDocumentObj.Descendants("User_Data")
               select Tuple.Create(item.Element("user").Value, item.Element("password").Value);

    return data.ToList();
}
```

Using these however, can often hide the meaning of return types. Since the method is public, you may be better creating a new class for the job:

```
 public class UserCredentials
 {
     public string Username {get; set; }
     public string Password {get; set; }
 }

 public List<UserCredentials> QueryXmlUserLogin() ...
```

As an aside, (based on the variable names) storing passwords in plaintext should not be done. Apologies if I'm incorrectly interpreting the variables or your example is contrived, but if anyone stumbles across this post - a hash of the password (and unique salt) should be stored rather than the password in plaintext.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't return anonymous types as they have this problem. Perhaps you should create a new data structure, construct it, then return a `List<T>` of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a type, for example:

```
class Person {
  public string User { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then use:

```
public List<Person> QueryXmlUserLogin()
{ 
   var data = from item in XDocumentObj.Descendants("User_Data")
        select new Person
        {
              User = item.Element("user").Value,
              Password = item.Element("password").Value,
        };

   return data.ToList();
}
```